# SQL INNER JOIN with LIKE and a WHERE

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause, sql-like

I have 2 tables. One called DocumentStatistics one called Documents. DocumentStatistics has a field called filename that contains a filename such as abcdef. Documents on the otherhand has a similar naming scheme but because it also holds old files they are numbered (for instance it might have abcdef1 and abcdef2). Only the latest document will be marked as islive=-1.

I would like to display the data from DocumentStatistics plus the correct cell from the Documents table.
Can someone help me? This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DocumentStatistics.*,Documents.tmpname
FROM DocumentStatistics
INNER JOIN Documents
ON DocumentStatistics.filename LIKE 'Documents.filename%'
WHERE Documents.islive=-1
```

Comment: I suggest working with primary and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can do it with SUBSTRING. Something like this:

```
SELECT DocumentStatistics.*,Documents.tmpname
FROM DocumentStatistics
LEFT JOIN Documents
ON SUBSTRING(DocumentStatistics.filename,start,length)= SUBSTRING(Documents.filename,start,length)
WHERE Documents.islive=-1
```

Comment: I am very new to this website. How do I accept yours as an answer?

Comment: There's a button somewhere to the left of my answer. I cannot really tell :)

Answer (score 1):

`like` is fine.  You just need to call it correctly:

```
SELECT ds.*, d.tmpname
FROM DocumentStatistics ds INNER JOIN
     Documents d
     ON ds.filename LIKE CONCAT(d.filename, '%')
WHERE d.islive = -1;
```

Your version was calling it with a constant string, rather than the name of a column.

I added table aliases to the query.  They make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: CONCAT is something I have not encountered before. Thanks for adding something to my toolbox.